# Redux Subscribe and update to UI

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am able to console log the increment and decrement results correctly during a button click. I am trying to update the UI using myStore.getState() but seems not working. How do I subscribe and update the UI? Many thanks and in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import counterReducer from './reducers'
import {increment,decrement} from './actions';

const myStore = createStore(counterReducer)

const handleIncrement = () => {
  myStore.dispatch(increment(2))
  console.log(myStore.getState())

}
const handleDecrement = () => {
  myStore.dispatch(decrement(2))
  console.log(myStore.getState())
}

function App() { 
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <h1>Counter {myStore.getState()}</h1>
       <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
       <button onClick={handleDecrement}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Could you add your actions and reducers, also can place your increase and decrease functions into your app function?

Comment: you might want to hook your functional component with the store. Check `useSelector` in [this example](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples)

Comment: I am able to console log the increment and decrement results correctly using console.log(myStore.getState()) but the UI part would not update. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) docs :

"useSelector() will also subscribe to the Redux store, and run your selector whenever an action is dispatched"

So every time you dispatch a action, `useSelector` hook will run and return a new `counter` value and re-render your component with new `counter`.

your `App` component might look something like this.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

function App() { 
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter)
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <h1>Counter {counter}</h1>
       <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
       <button onClick={handleDecrement}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Using Redux subscribe

```
function App() { 
  const [state, updateState] = React.useState({});
  // subscribing to the redux store
  store.subscribe(() => updateState(store.getState()))
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <h1>Counter {state.counter}</h1>
       <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
       <button onClick={handleDecrement}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to learn redux as much as possible. is it possible to not use react-redux? I have used react-redux as you have mentioned and it works. I have come to know about the Subscribe method of the Store but I just do not know how to update the UI using the Subscribe method. Thanks

Comment: @Nat I've updated my answer. Firstly you subscribe to the store and whenever you are notified, you update the local states and which will re-render your component.

Comment: redux `subscribe` can be used as I explained but you'd use a view binding library like `react-redux` if you want to bind your store with your react-app

Comment: `store.subscribe()` is an unintentional side-effect, so you should certainly use the `useEffect` hook in this use case. Using `store.subscribe` in a React component like this though is also a bit of an anti-pattern. Just stick to using the `useSelector` hook to subscribe to state changes.